# Unit testing - how to test method calls of interface

Tags: android, kotlin, unit-testing

I have a json parser that parse json of incoming signals. The parser receives an Interface of methods that can call, the method is decided by the siganl. i.e:

```
{
   "type": "method1",
   "light" : false
}
```

and

```
{
  "type": "method2",
  "time": 12345
}
```

The interface looks like this:

```
  interface SignalsInterface {

     fun method1(light: Boolean)
     fun method2(time: Long)
  }
```

I want to test the parser by inputing the parser with json from txt file, and check if the right method is being called. Is there a canonical way to do that? What is the industry standard?

Answer (score 1):

MockK allows you to `verify` that a method was called.

https://mockk.io/#dsl-examples

Mockito also allows you to `verify` that a method was called.

https://javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html#1

Both of these follow a similar pattern, but I will present the mockk way of doing this:

```kotlin
@Test
fun test() {
  // init mock
  val mockSignalsInterface = mockk<SignalsInterface>()
  every { mockSignalsInterface.method1(any()) } returns Unit

  // init unit to test
  val parser = YourParser(mockSignalsInterface)
  parser.parse(YOUR_TEST_INPUT)

  // verify method called
  verify { mockSignalsInterface.method1(false) }
}
```

Also, I would be remiss if I did not link the owasp guidelines for input validation here, since your code appears to accept arbitrary inputs and execute code based off of them: https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Input_Validation_Cheat_Sheet.html